# MySql как делать бекап и проводить тестирование на windows?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет! 
Написал наконец то программку и пришло время настраивать MySql.
MySql установлен на Windows 7. Начал искать программы для тестов и для эталонного тестирования, но все что я не находил работает только на linux.
Подскажите каким софтом пользуются под Windows? Все таблицы InnoDB. 
Я бы с удовольствием поставил Mysql на какую нибудь Ubuntu, но я вообще никогда не сталкивался с линуксом!
Спасибо всем кто откликнется!

Comment: виртуалку на виндос поставить не проблема, virtualbox например

Comment: каких тестов? что вы хотите тестировать?

Comment: Виртуалка для резервного копирования? Я не думал что это самый простой и правильный выход!
Хотелось бы иметь тесты потипу sysbench.

Comment: С бекапом разобрался! Оказывается mysqldump.exe идет вместе с сервером MySql и лежит в паке bin.
Работает так же как и на линуксе.
Вопрос с тестами БД остается открытым!